# Detecting when native select widget is opened/closed in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, uiwebview

When the user clicks on a `select` box in `UIWebView`, a native popover is displayed at the bottom of the screen with the available options. The webpage contents scroll up to make room for this popover.

It seems like no DOM event is fired when this scroll happens, although the value of `body.scrollTop` does change. Is there any way to detect when the popover is opened, or do we have to use `setInterval` to poll and watch for `scrollTop` changing?

Comment: Is it possible for you to make modifications to the iOS application (e.g.) evaluate a JavaScript code within your web view?

Comment: We might be able to implement some sort of notifications on the native side, but theoretically I'd like this to work in Safari as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that the scroll event isn't firing. [MDN has a list of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) that can be bound to that might be of help to you.

A quick thought that jumps out to me is that you could bind to the mouseup and input/change events on the select and in their callbacks determine what the scrollTop is as the user interacts with the select. If you have multiple selects you need to track, you could delegate the events to the body to avoid creating additional listeners.

Polling would work, but it'd be a lot less efficient then adding a few event listeners on the select itself, so hopefully you can find an event that works.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Binding to the `click` event on the `select` is OK for detecting when it opens, but there's no way I can see to detect when the native popover closes since there is no interaction with the page at all in that case. I've resorted to polling and observing `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: Granting the bounty although this is only a partial answer. I gather that there is no way to detect the popover close without resorting to polling.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this is by setting a listener on the UIPicker with a WebView delegate. This listener can then call an appropriate function in your JS:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    ...

    // UIWebViewDelegate protocol for WebView load
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
        // Set observer for keyboard load event
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification){
        // Call JavaScript function in the WebView
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("yourJSFunction()")
    }
}
```